# Area of a rasterised not-quite circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am creating rasterised circles centred on a particular cell, and determining what other cells are inside the circle with the equation

abs(centreX - cellX)^2 + abs(centreY - cellY)^2 <= radius * radius + radius

Its not quite pythagorean (making it not quite a circle) because of the extra +radius which makes the circles mathematically fatter, but more visually appealing on the grid. Another wierd thing which may be relevant is that the diameter of all the circles created this way is radius*2+1.

I am trying to find out the integer volume of a circle of a given radius, but given the above mutilation of normal circular concepts its a bit too tricky for me..

Comment: Isn't this just the same as using the usual inequality for a circle of radius $\sqrt{r^2 + r}$?

Comment: @Anthony: $d=2\sqrt{r^2+r}=2r\sqrt{1+1/r}\approx 2r(1+1/(2r)) = 2r+1$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: sure, but I don't understand how this is "not quite a circle" or that the "normal circular concepts" are being "mutilated".

Comment: What he's trying to do is essentially [Gauss' Circle Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html).

Comment: Sorry, Im not a math guy, Im a programmer... All I know is that the pythagorean formula is inherintly linked to circles, but I changed it by adding more weight to the right, which to me means its not quite so linked anymore. IDK.

Comment: The more interesting question is: How do you define _integer volume_? Is it the standard volume rounded to the next integer, or is it the number of (unit spaced) grid points strictly inside (or inside or on) your boundary?

Comment: The number of grid points for which the above formula is true. The Gauss' Circle Problem link is the correct kind of thing I'm looking for, I am currtly trying to hammer it into shape as a line of code so I can use the radius described by Anthony and see if it works.

Comment: I'd say that your code is not doing what you think it's doing. You seem to think that are modifying the "Pythagorean" definition of a circle, and thereby making something non-circular. But, as others have noted, that's not what you're doing. Your shapes are still perfectly circular, but they have a radius of $\sqrt{r^2 + r}$, rather than a radius of $r$.

Comment: Also, you don't need the "abs" in your code, because abs(thing)^2 is the same as (thing)^2.

Comment: Thanks bubba, the change in appearance of the circles on the grid led me to errornously beleive that the resulting shape was slightly squared, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

$$1 + 4 \sum_{j=0}^{r^2/4}\left( \frac{r^2}{4j+1} - \frac{r^2}{4j+3}\right)$$
is the formula for working out the filled cells for a "regular" circle ([source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html)), so substituting $\sqrt{r^2+r}$ as the radius I get:

$$1 + 4\sum_{j=0}^{(r^2+r)/4}\left(\frac{r^2+r}{4j+1} - \frac{r^2+r}{4j+3}\right)$$

Which when tested matches the area of my circles calculated by a manual count.

Slightly bummed I have to perform a loop to get the answer rather than figuring it out in one line.

While none directly answered my question, full props to commenters for helping me put the pieces together - anyone giving +1 this answer, please also +1 their comments.

**edit:**

Anyone trying to apply this to programming, and realising that $\frac{r^2+r}{4}$ performance is actually awful, you are better off looping r+1 times with:

$$1 + 4\sum_{j=0}^{r+1}\left(\sqrt{r^2-j^2}\right)$$

which is equivilant to the above.